# Click on the graph core-plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

How to do that when you click on the graph, on the point (shows the value at that point)?

And how it make if i have 4 graph on one view.

Any examples?

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example apps included with Core Plot. The *Plot Gallery* has an example of adding a label when the user clicks a plot. The Mac version of *CPTTestApp* shows another technique of drawing a crosshairs over the selected point on a scatter plot.

Each plot has its own delegate that will be notified of the click. The delegate methods all have the sending plot as one of the parameters so you can use the same delegate object to handle more than one plot.

Comment: Due to the plot gallery containing loads of sample it would be great if you could provide a link to a file implementing the appropriate delegate.